# Combining Arrays within an Array

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, merge

I am currently trying to generate a random dataset based on a choice of k, the number of clusters, and xlim and ylim as the boundaries to be inputted. I want my output to be as follows:

```
[array([11.7282981 ,  6.89656728],
        [ 9.88391172,  5.83611126],
        [7.45631652, 7.88674093],
        [8.38232831, 7.82884638])
```

This code is for k means project

Here is my attempt. First I create a cluster center, which is randomly generated within a range between 0 and xlimit and ylimit inputted. Then I create 2 (in this case 2 but I will be doing 100) random points around the cluster center with noise:

```
k = 2
xlim = 12
ylim = 12

f = []
for x in range(0,k):
    
    clusterCenter = [random.randint(0,xlim),random.randint(0,ylim)]
    cluster = np.random.randn(2, 2) + clusterCenter
    f.append(cluster)

f
```

unfortunately the output comes out to be:

```
[array([[11.7282981 ,  6.89656728],
        [ 9.88391172,  5.83611126]]),
 array([[7.45631652, 7.88674093],
        [8.38232831, 7.82884638]])]
```

which is not what I want as I would like to put this into a pandas dataframe. can anyone help?

the numbers will be a lot greater, I have made it such that the cluster generated would be a set of 2 x and y co-ordinates, but would ideally want:

```
    cluster = np.random.randn(100, 2) + clusterCenter
```

So keep that in consideration! any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `f.append(cluster)` with:

```
f = None # instead of []
...
    if f is None:
        f = cluster
    else:        
        f = np.concatenate( (f, cluster) )
```

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-b69137fe8c8d> in <module>
     11     #if counter == 0:
     12     #    f.append(cluster)
---> 13     if f:
     14         f = np.concatenate((f, cluster))
     15     else:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() I got this error with your solution?

Comment: Ah, cripes.   OK, I'll mod the answer slightly.  It would be nice to create a 0x2 array, but I don't think numpy allows that.

Comment: no problem thanks a lot for the help! really appreciate it that works now! I knew it had something to do with the way f was initialised being a different format to the arrays being concacatenated to it but I couldn't figure out how to fix it! I'm quite new to programming so really appreciate the help!